# group by query works php 5.4, not php 7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am upgrading my project from PHP 5.4, Laravel 4.2 to PHP 7.4, Laravel 6. My database is MySql 5.5.60-0+deb7u1, this hasn't changed.

I have a query that works with PHP 5.4, Laravel 4.2, that does not work with PHP 7.4, Laravel 6 and I can't figure out why. Below is my query and my error.

Error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'iddev1.c.formattedName' isn't in GROUP BY
(SQL:
SELECT
`c`.`formattedName`,
`d`.`documentNo`,
`d`.`status`,
`d`.`dateOpen`,
`d`.`dateClosed`,
SUM(t.amountTotal) AS sum_total
FROM `transactions` AS `t`
LEFT JOIN `documents` AS `d` ON `d`.`id` = `t`.`documentId`
LEFT JOIN `contacts` AS `c` ON `c`.`id` = `d`.`contactId`
WHERE `t`.`tenantId` = 15 AND `t`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL
 AND `t`.`date` >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND `t`.`date` <= '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY `t`.`documentId`
ORDER BY `c`.`formattedName` ASC, `d`.`documentNo` ASC
)
```

Why am I getting this error with PHP 7?
The query is valid, I can successfully run the query on the database in HeidiSQL.
It only fails when I run it through PHP 7 and Laravel 6.

Comment: Error suggests your mysql version updated to +5.7. You sure your DB instances is the same, also error is from DB, not PHP.

Comment: Yes, DB is info is correct. Using PHP 7, query fails, in HeidiSQL, query works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update `strict` mode to `false` in database file

```
'strict' => false
```

default is true

Please check below an array of config/database.php

```
'mysql' => ['strict' => false]
```

Comment: @user3720435 But note that some would regard this as an appallingly bad idea. Far better to leave 'strict mode' alone and add the remaining columns to the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  Right now I'm trying to upgrade my version of PHP, not re-write everything.